# Rendering HTML output as JSON in Firefox

Tags: html, json, firefox, mime

I have a file `persons.json`, containing:

```
[
  {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
  {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
  {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

When I open it in Firefox, it invokes the JSON viewer, like this:

[image]

However, I would like to achieve the same thing when opening an HTML file, `persons.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="application/json; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
[
  {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
  {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
  {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Which Firefox renders to:

[image]

How can I force Firefox to render the HTML file's output as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is a JSON renderer, a simple google search would give you a few options, here's a simple library I found that you can use https://dev.to/smrgrg/rendering-json-data-in-html-489o